# How to render while in the compositor?

Tags: rendering, interface, node-editor

In a [tutorial](http://youtu.be/VcRJJphKC7s) at 3:22 the guy rendered while in node editor, but didn't say how.

I have tried other tutorials but they all don't say how to do this.

Comment: Could you link to the tutorial and time in question?

Comment: @user4935 with that little information is hard to know what your problem is or how to help you. Please expand on what you've tried that didn't work, and what tutorial you're referring to.

Comment: here is the link to the tutorial http://youtu.be/VcRJJphKC7s and the question is 3 minutes and 22 seconds into the vido. Thank you and good luck.

Comment: @user4935 You can render anywhere by pressing F12.

Comment: To see a rendered image in the background of the compositor window, the backdrop option needs to be checked. The image displayed is whatever is plugged to a viewer node. If what you want to display is part of the rendered layers, the image needs to be rendered first by pressing f12. Check this tutorial: http://cgcookie.com/blender/2011/01/11/tip-rendering-with-a-background-image/

Answer (score 1):

At `3:22` he renders the scene by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>.

You can render by

- Pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>.
- Pressing *Render image* in *Info header > Render*:

  [image]
- Pressing *Render* in *Properties > Render settings > Render*:

  [image]

Answer (score 1):

You can also render without leaving the compositor by pressing the Camera icon in the Render Layers node:

[image]